# Spring boot rest service deployment on tomcat : unable to find jdbc

Tags: spring-boot

My spring boot rest service MAVEN based app works fine in Eclipse workspace. I am able to generate WAR without any issues. However, when I deploy to tomcat, it's unable to bind my data sources from context.xml. Exact error is below.

Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/MyDB] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:817)

Here is what I have done so far based on other posts on stackoverflow.

1. My context.xml has javax.sql.DataSource resource defined along with resourceLink. Code pasted below.
2. my pom.xml has build section with resources and plugins. Code pasted below.
3. my applicationContext.xml has bean defined for class org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean with property jndiName pinting to jdbc resource defined in context xml.
4. Initially, I found that context xml was not being included in war by maven build, hence I copied meta-inf directory under main/java/resources folder as some of the posts suggested. Now the context xml does get included in war under meta-inf folder.
5. When I deploy the war, it's unable to start and logs error below.
   Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/MyDB] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
   at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:817)

Context xml ==>

```
   <context>
    <Resource name="jdbc/MyDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        username="uid" password="pwd" driverClassName="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"
        url="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://myserver:1433/mydatabase" maxActive="8"
        maxIdle="4" validationQuery="select 1" />

         <ResourceLink name="jdbc/MyDB"
             global="jdbc/MyDB"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
      </context>
```

pom.xml==>

```
    <build>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <!-- this is relative to the pom.xml directory -->
                        <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <configuration>
                                <mainClass>com.passg.springboot.SpringBootRestApiApp</mainClass>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
```

applicationContext.xml ==>

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

            <bean id="myDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
                <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/MyDB"/>
            </bean>
```

Error ==>

```
    Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/MyDB] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:817)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:159)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:827)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:159)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:827)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:173)
        at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:163)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
        at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$1.doInContext(JndiTemplate.java:155)
        at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:87)
        at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:152)
        at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:179)
        at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:95)
        at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectLocator.lookup(JndiObjectLocator.java:106)
        at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.lookupWithFallback(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:231)
        at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:217)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1648)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1585)
        ... 110 more
```

I somehow need my deployed tomcat app to be able to recognize context xml and make jndi connection. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

woooohoo! I could finally figure out the answer thanks to another post on stackoverflow!! It was stupidest mistake I have ever made I think. In my context xml, element "context" should have been with uppercase "C" i.e. "Context"!!

Thanks to guys in this link!

[Trouble Deploying WAR file. Failed to start component []](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26348210/trouble-deploying-war-file-failed-to-start-component)